# How to change X and Z axes of rigidbody’s velocity only?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im new in unity so I need help. My player movement controller works by adding something to rigidbody’s velocity, but then player falls
too slow. I know, that I must change velocity only by X and Z, but how?
Edit: I have Vector3 that is input and speed. So rigidbody.velocity = input * speed;

Comment: How are you updating the velocity now?

Comment: Hi!. Definitely, not enough information is provided to answer effectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently setting the rigidbody velocity like this:

```
rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(xSpeed, 0, zSpeed);
```

Where xSpeed and zSpeed are your variables/inputs to move around. The reason why the player falls slowly is then because you are repeatedly setting the Y velocity to 0. Try something like this:

```
rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(xSpeed, rigidbody.velocity.y, zSpeed);
```

However, if you are adding to the velocity, then you would do this:

```
rigidbody.velocity += new Vector3(xSpeedIncrease, 0.0f, ySpeedIncrease);
```

Both of these makes it so the Y velocity will not change when you set the X or Z velocities.

Answer (score 0):

So just to clarify, the axis in which force is applied is defined by the vector you use with the Rigidbodies velocity/AddForce function.

Here is an example:

```
Rigidbody rb;
float moveSpeed = 50.0f;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    //You only need one of these lines, I just want to show some examples.

    //This is how we apply force in the axis that we want, in this case X and Z:
    rb.AddForce(new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    //To then speed up this force, we can multiply it by a speed factor:
    rb.AddForce(new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) * moveSpeed * Time.DeltaTime //Time.DeltaTime makes us framerate independant
}
```

When you say your player is falling, I get the feeling that you have gravity enabled on the Rigidbody? If you don't want the player to fall then this will be the cause of it falling, and it will fall regardless of the force you apply providing it is above ground, as a Rigidbody is a physics simulation.

If this isn't what you want then a Rigidbody is probably overkill. You can just move the player around with no physics using Transform.translate.

If you do want a Rigidbody but just want the player to fall slower, then you could reduce the gravity force on the Rigidbody in the inspector.

Comment: I want to my player falling, but falling’s speed is very, very small.